# ¿Cómo puedo agregar php en una clase con las etiquetas <i>?

Tags: wordpress, php7, wordpress-theme

Tengo el siguiente código

```
$icono = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'icono', true);
<span>
      <i class="<?php echo $icono;?>"></i>
```

```
function la_descripcion() {
global $wpdb, $post;
$icono  = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'icono', true);

echo '<label><strong>Icono para el post</strong></label></br>
<input type="text" name="icono" id="icono" value="'.htmlspecialchars($icono).'" style="width: 300px;" /></br></br>';
```

}

Estoy usando Wordpress, desarrollando un theme a medida, Este,es un Metabox donde en teoría debería capturar un campo de texto (fa-solid fa-clouds) con lo cuál agregaría esa clase para mostrar el icono que corresponde. pero no funciona
¿Podrían ayudarme?
Agradezco de antemano el tiempo y ayuda que me puedan prestar.

Comment: En la etiqueta de apertura `label` te sobra `"`.

Comment: Con las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador verifica que tengas cargada fontawesome; y revisa -y compártenos- el resultado final del tanto del `<input>` como del `<i>`.

Comment: le falta información a tu pregunta, ya tienes font awesome encolado, si hacer var dump devuelve texto plano, un array o toda la etiqueta, si inspeccionas como se muestra en el fronted? por favor lee [ask] y como hacer un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Estaba colocando fuera de loop el elemento <i> por lo cual me tomaba el valor en 0 ó vació, declare la variable dentro del loop y funciono correctamente. Muchas gracias a todos por su tiempo y sus respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$icono = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'icono', true);
  <i class="<?php echo $icono;?>"></i>
```

Esta declaración la realice dentro del loop de wordpres.
De esta manera recorre cada post y busca el custompost de cada uno, y lo muestra en caso de tener algo para mostrar.